# ZF2 Greater than / Less than query

Tags: select, zend-framework2

SQL Query

```
Select * FROM table_name 
WHERE category = 'category_name' 
AND created < 'todays_date' 
AND created > 'yesterdays_date'
```

Also need to add ORDER and LIMIT conditions.
How can I achieve this in ZF2?

I have this code:

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function ($select) {
        $select->where(['category' => $this->category]);
        $select->order('id Desc');
        $select->limit($this->limit);

        $DBtimeNow = new \DateTime();
        $select->lessThanOrEqualTo("created", $DBtimeNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $DBtimeNow->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $select->greaterThanOrEqualTo("created", $DBtimeNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Predicate object as you want to use operators: `<=` and `>=` in this case. You can get those by using this component `Zend\Db\Sql\Where` of `Zend\Db` of ZF2 as it extends `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate`. And then we would be able to use those operators when we need. Please check out the following:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

// here is the catch
$predicate = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();

$select->where(['category' => $this->category]);

// now use thus
$DBtimeNow = new \DateTime();
$select->where($predicate->lessThanOrEqualTo("created", $DBtimeNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 'AND');
$DBtimeNow->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$select->where($predicate->greaterThanOrEqualTo("created", $DBtimeNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 'AND');

$select->order('id Desc');
$select->limit($this->limit);

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```